# statically compile a Nim program in macOS

Tags: compilation, nim-lang

I'm writing a program in Nim using the `zip/zipfiles` library, which relies on *libzip(|2|4).dylib*.

My question is primarily for macOS, but guidance for Linux is also welcome.

How can I compile it to have a statically linked binary to be easier to distribute?

Thanks
Andrea

EDIT:
Apparently something like https://nim-lang.org/docs/nimc.html#dynliboverride should do.
Specifically for this library, `-p:useLibzipSrc` also does.

Comment: As an option you could consider using recently released zippy which is a pure Nim library (but you will need to change your code): see release announcement https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/7054

Comment: I'll keep an eye on that, thanks @pietroppeter -- but the question remains relevant to me like this

Comment: there is a PR for having static linking by default for linux, it might work also for macos: https://github.com/nim-lang/zip/pull/38 To try if that works for you probably the easiest way would be to install directly the fork (`nimble install https://github.com/brentp/zip`)

Comment: note that probably the first thing you should try is to use `-d:useLibzipSrc` as suggested by @recruit_main707 in a comment of his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading through the source it seems like you may be able to do this by passing `-d:useLibzipSrc`

Comment: No, I want to compile the program a CLI application (default) but statically linking the library instead of dynamically linking it. Probably the correct term is "static build"

Comment: I see, reading through the source it seems like you may be able to do this by passing `-d:useLibzipSrc`

Comment: Yes, for the specific library this works, thanks. Do you want to amend your answer?